# load aria now values according to predetermined numbers in asc or desc order

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have a 5 star user rating system and would like the progress bars to load accordingly i.e if the user has 2 `5-star` ratings and 10 `1-star` ratings the progress bar should show this. so far i retrieve the users rates (1 to 5) and store them in an array i.e

```js
var rate= {
  str1: 100,
  str2: 20,
  str3: 30,
  str4: 40,
  str5: 50
};
```

then i sort the array in asc order

```js
function bySortedValue(obj, callback, context) {
  var tuples = [];

  for (var key in obj) tuples.push([key, obj[key]]);

  tuples.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] < b[1] ? 1 : a[1] > b[1] ? -1 : 0
  });

  var length = tuples.length;
  while (length--) callback.call(context, tuples[length][0], tuples[length][1]);
}
//example
bySortedValue(arru, function(key, value) {
  document.getElementById('res').innerHTML += `${key}: ${value}<br>`;
  


});
```

then i have another array that holds the aria values to be loaded according to the rate size of the rate array i.e the lowest rating would get a value of `28%` width

```js
var aria= [28,48,68,88,98];
```

my problem is that i cant figure out how to tie all this together to be loaded via jquery into the progress bar to look like this

```html
<div class="progblock">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link-muted str-nmb-5">
    <div class="progress skill-bar ">
      <div class="prgbfi progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="88" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
        <span class="skill five-rt">5 <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-user val"> 50</i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link-muted str-nmb-4">
    <div class="progress skill-bar">
      <div class="prgbfo progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="68" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
        <span class="skill four-rt">4 <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-user val"> 40</i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link-muted str-nmb-3">
    <div class="progress skill-bar">
      <div class="prgbth progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="48" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
        <span class="skill three-rt">3 <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-user val"> 30</i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link-muted str-nmb-2">
    <div class="progress skill-bar">
      <div class="prgbtw progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="28" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
        <span class="skill two-rt">2 <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-user val"> 20</i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link-muted str-nmb-1">
    <div class="progress skill-bar">
      <div class="prgbon progress-bar progress-bar-dis" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="98" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
        <span class="skill one-rt">1 <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-user val"> 100</i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/idwapro/r82akge6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out

```js
arru = {
  prgbon: res[index].Son,
  prgbtw: res[index].Stw,
  prgbth: res[index].Sth,
  prgbfo: res[index].Sfo,
  prgbfi: res[index].Sfi
};

nar = [];

bySortedValue(arru, function(key, value) {
  
  nar.push(key);

});

$('.progress .' + nar[0]).css("width", function() {
  return $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + "28%";
});
$('.progress .' + nar[1]).css("width", function() {
  return $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + "48%";
});
$('.progress .' + nar[2]).css("width", function() {
  return $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + "68%";
});
$('.progress .' + nar[3]).css("width", function() {
  return $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + "88%";
});
$('.progress .' + nar[4]).css("width", function() {
  return $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + "98%";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var aria= [28,48,68,88,98];
for(i=0; i < aria.length; i++){

$('.progblock').append('<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link-muted str-nmb-5"><div class="progress skill-bar "><div class="prgbfi progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="' + aria[i] + '" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"><span class="skill five-rt">5 <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-user val"> 50</i></span></div></div></a>');
}
$('.progress .progress-bar').css("width", function() {
  return $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + "%";
});
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="progblock">

</div>
```

below

Comment: it needs to load based on the star values not the aria array